# How to fix bug Unexpected token in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, text

I want to check when date < 12 it will return AM and when date > 12 it will return PM
I tried to do it but it doesn't seem to work

here is my code:

```
<Text>
    { date ? ({item.date} AM):({item?.date }PM)}
 </Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Text>
    {item.date < 12 ? `${item.date} AM` : `${item.date} PM`}
</Text>
```

Maybe you can try using a library to handle dates:

- date-fns
- List item
- day.js
- spacetime
- luxon

Comment: thanks for your help but it doesn't seem to be what i want because when i run it all turns out to be PM